# Check if object with specific property value exists in an array

Tags: coffeescript

Im still trying to learn CoffeeScript, so im simply asking how you would write this code in a more simple way.

```
for member in draft.members
        if member.email is emailAddress then throw new Meteor.Error 500, "Cannot add member twice"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step one is making it readable:

```
for member in draft.members
    if member.email is emailAddress
        throw new Meteor.Error 500, 'Cannot add member twice'
```

We can eliminate the `if`-expression using `when`:

```
for member in draft.members when member.email is emailAddress
    throw new Meteor.Error 500, 'Cannot add member twice'
```

Please don't write hideous long lines. Remember that `if`-expressions can span multiple lines.

---

As for a complete alternative, you can eliminate the `for`-expression if you use Underscore.js or jQuery. Here is an example using Underscore.js (if you prefer jQuery, see `$.grep`):

```
if _.find(draft.members, (m) -> m.email is emailAddress)
    throw new Meteor.Error 500, 'Cannot add member twice'
```

IMO, the `for`-expression with `when` is most readable.

Comment: Thanks, i agree that the `for-when` is the most readable one, and exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which results in quite simple JS and does not require external libraries :)

```
emailAlreadyUsed = draft.members.some (m) -> m.email is emailAddress
throw new Meteor.Error 500, 'Cannot add member twice' if emailAlreadyUsed
```